# How can I use AppleScriptObjC to close my Xcode application?

Tags: xcode, macos, applescript, applescript-objc

I have an AppleScriptObjC Xcode application.  Within this application, I've built an updater that checks for updates on startup and will prompt the user to download them.  Everything works wonderfully - except for one thing.  I need the app to restart when it is updated, so the changes can take effect.  I've searched high and low on the internet for this, but I can't figure it out.  I cannot to "tell application \"MyApp\" to quit", because Xcode doesn't allow that.  Any ideas?

Comment: Any reason you're rolling your own update solution instead of using [Sparkle](http://sparkle.andymatuschak.org/)?

Comment: @duskwuff Not really, but I do like the one I have.  Anyway, do you know how to close it?

Answer (score 1):

This is an Objective-C-Method to re-launch. May be you can use the idea.

```
+(void)restart:(id)sender
{
    NSString *restartScript = @"while ps -p $1 > /dev/null; do sleep 0.1; done; open \"$2\"";
    NSArray *arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          @"-c", restartScript,
                          @"",
                          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processIdentifier]],
                          [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath],
                          nil];
    [NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:@"/bin/sh" arguments:arguments];
    [NSApp terminate:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to quit the app, using the command `quit` seems to work fine. If you want it to *relaunch* (without using Objective-C) you could try starting a separate script just before quitting that does something like this:

```
delay 2
tell application "Name of Application" to activate
```

I hope this idea helps.